# Adding hidden layers to first simple neural network

Tags: tensorflow

I have read many beginner books of tensorflow
and made this code.
This simply takes N dimension data and output 1 dimension.

It works well charmingly!!

Now, I want to add hidden layer to this, however I can't make it and find simple tutorial or samples to understand how to add hidden layer.

Is there good practice or ideas ?? or 
"Adding hidden layer to this sample" is correct approach to learn further???

```
tf.set_random_seed(0)
N = 10

w = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([N,1])) 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,N]) 
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])
y = tf.nn.sigmoid(tf.matmul(x,w) + b)

cross_entropy = - tf.reduce_sum(t * tf.log(y) + (1 -t) * tf.log(1 -y))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)


init = tf.global_variables_initializer()
sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

for epoch in range(2000):
    sess.run(train_step,feed_dict={
        x: X,
        t: Y
    })

classified = correct_prediction.eval(session=sess,feed_dict={
    x:X,
    t:Y
    })

print(classified)

prob = y.eval(session=sess ,feed_dict={
    x:X,
    t:Y
})
print(prob)

print('w:',sess.run(w))
print('b:',sess.run(b))
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your hidden layer will be between the input and output layers, so the input-hidden layer will be connected by weights of size `[input_size, hidden_size]` and hidden-output layer will be connected by weights of size `[hidden_size, output_size]`. And there will be activations at each layer.

Your code should look like:

```
N = 10
n_hidden = 20
# dont initialise weights to zero but to a small number
w_h = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([N,n_hidden], stddev=0.001)) 
b_h = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([n_hidden]))

w = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([n_hidden,1], stddev=0.001)) 
b = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([1]))

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,N]) 
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])

h = tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(x, w_h) + b_h)

y = tf.matmul(h, w) + b

#remove sigmoid from last layer and use the stable implementation:
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=y, labels=t))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.1).minimize(cross_entropy)
correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.to_float(tf.greater(y,0.5)),t)
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear explanation. I could understand.

Answer (score 3):

Why not use tf.layers?

```
N = 10
n_hidden = 20

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,N])
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])

layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x,n_hidden,tf.nn.relu)
y = tf.layers.dense(layer1,1)
```

adding more layers changes the above to say:

```
N = 10
n_hidden_1 = 20
n_hidden_2 = 25

x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,N])
t = tf.placeholder(tf.float32,shape=[None,1])

layer1 = tf.layers.dense(x,n_hidden_1,tf.nn.relu)
layer2 = tf.layers.dense(layer1,n_hidden_2,tf.nn.relu)
y = tf.layers.dense(layer1,1)
```

Comment: I will search and try about tf.layer. thank you very much.